# Get a list of markers/layers within current map bounds in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This is somewhat similar to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755219/find-layers-in-current-map-view-with-leafletjs) --

I'm writing a search box for a map application, which retrieves a whole set of search results (people's names & info) at once from a server and then pages through the list of results. So at any given point on the map there are two kinds of markers -- a background marker for points which are in the search results but not in the current page, and a foreground marker for points which are in the current page of search results.

All this works nicely.. what I'd like to do now is set it up so that if a user zooms or pans the map, the search results list updates to show only markers within the current map bounds.

Obviously there are server-side ways to do this, or I could also just run through the whole list of markers to see which fit within the current bounds; but does anybody know a built-in way to do this within leaflet? Something which would look like map.getVisibleLayers()?

Answer (score 20):

I think this may be of help:
https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-list-markers

as you can see from the demo, including all markers in a layer, this plugin shows a list of only those visible in the current viewport.
Its usage is simple, in a row:

```
var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();
map.addControl( new L.Control.ListMarkers({layer: markersLayer}) );
```

The code for obtain it is like as:

```
var layers = L.LayerGroup(), //layers contains all markers..
    contained = [];          //makers in map boundingbox

layers.eachLayer(function(l) {
    if( l instanceof L.Marker && map.getBounds().contains(l.getLatLng()) )
        contained.push(l);
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's a fully working function that does the job:

```
// var map is an instance of a Leaflet map
// this function assumes you have added markers as GeoJSON to the map
// it will return an array of all features currently shown in the
// active bounding region.

function getFeaturesInView() {
  var features = [];
  map.eachLayer( function(layer) {
    if(layer instanceof L.Marker) {
      if(map.getBounds().contains(layer.getLatLng())) {
        features.push(layer.feature);
      }
    }
  });
  return features;
}
```

Comment: very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Using this code I can't get list of markers at the very first time when map load. Is there any ways to get that?

Comment: @HarshPatel You might need to use some event listeners like `map.on('load', () => { });`or wait until all the markers are loaded with `marker.on('add', function (el) { })`

Answer (score 12):

You have to check the bounds of each layer versus the map's bounds. Because eachLayer() returns all layers regardless of whether they are in the visible extent.

```
if(map.getBounds().contains(layer.getLatLng())) { ... }
```

In Stefano's code, this is shown around this line:

https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-list-markers/blob/master/src/leaflet-list-markers.js#L95

Answer (score 8):

Regarding the last part of your question, if you want to iterate through visible layers, you can use eachLayer, e.g:

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    // do something with the layer
});
```

API reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-stuff-methods

Comment: I bellieve that iterates over _all_ layers, not just the visible ones.